# Cardboard Unity3D. how to animate a rotation + head tracking

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm new. While creating a rail system for my camera, the position animations where fine. However, when I created rotation animation on the "y" axis of my camera, the Unity Editor incorporated them, but the final product relied on head tracking only. I'm guessing that I need to multiply my animation values by the head tracking values, but I'm not sure how to do this. For starters, I don't know how to obtain the animation values. I was planning to set them and forget them, but it's never that easy. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent object over the camera and animate it instead. The head tracking SETS the orientation of the head object, so it overrides your animation. But the orientation it sets is local in respect to the objects parent in the hierarchy, so if you move/rotate the parent, the camera rig will also be moved/rotated.

If you are using the `CardboardMain` prefab, then `CardboardMain` is the parent of the `Head` you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CarboardMain prefab, then animate the root gameobject, not the MainCamera or the Head.

Comment: Thanks guys! That's much easier than I thought. And yes I was trying to animate head.